# ending for loop if condition is met

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

How can I end a for loop if a condition is met inside it?

I want to break a for loop once t = 1 for example, but as of now I am only breaking out of an if statement inside the for loop.

```
t = 0
x = matrix()
for (i in 1:10){
   if (t == 1){
       break }
   t = t + 0.01
   x[i] = t
}
```

Comment: there is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082655/r-break-for-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean, `for (i in 1:101)`, you won't get a value equal to `1` in the loop because `.01` cannot be exactly represented in binary.

With the modified `for` statement, the 100'th value is not exactly equal to 1:

```
x[100] - 1
## [1] 6.661338e-16
```

To break when something "exceeds or equals" another value, you would use `>=`.  That is, modify the test to read `if (t >= 1) { break }`.  In general, you should not use `==` to compare floating-point numbers.

Comment: I apologize for setting an arbitrary example that was incorrect. But I think my point is clear. How can I break out of a for loop if a variable exceeds or equals to some value

Comment: Your code is already correct, it is the example numbers that are wrong. Try it with integers.