# How can I "break" out of a For loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Below, when I execute the `goto` command, it just hangs and I have to Control-C.  I tried `EXIT /b` too. I'm trying to avoid goto's as much as possible.  Is there a way to do what I want?

```
:SUB_bigRandLooper

set /a lcv=0

FOR /L %%s IN ( 0 , 0 , 1 ) DO (

    set big-rand=!random:~-4!
    echo big-rand is !big-rand!
    set /a lcv=%lcv+1
    if !big-rand! GTR 9900 goto bigRandLooperWrapup
)

:bigRandLooperWrapup

echo biggest-rand is %big-rand%
echo lcv is %lcv%

EXIT /B
```

.

Comment: You should be able to use break. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082655/r-break-for-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa .

Comment: @steck, your link is pointing to a different scripting language.  In a normal for loop you can break out of it using a GOTO command.  But a FOR /L does not let you do that.  We have a thread about this on DosTips.com that I will dig up.

Comment: Here is the thread on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2707)

Comment: do you want to break out of the loop completely or break out when the value is greater than, then return to the loop and reprocess the rest?

Comment: `set /a lcv=%lcv+1` should read `set /a lcv=lcv+1`, or even `set /a lcv+=1`...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No, you can't.

---

Since you are using `for /L` and establish an infinite loop and the fact that the loop is preprocessed and cached before it is executed, it cannot be interrupted by `goto`; `goto` breaks the loop context, or more correctly spoken, the `(`/`)` block context, so no more commands in the block are executed, but the loop itself is still running.

You can prove this by the following code:

```cmd
for /L %%I in (1,1,100000) do (
    echo %%I
    if %%I equ 10 goto :SKIP
)
:SKIP
echo skipped
```

You will see that `echo %%I` is only executed for `%%I` from `1` to `10`, but execution does not immediately continue at `echo skipped` but there is a notable delay, because the loop finishes iterating in the background, although no more commands are executed.

---

There is a work-around though: you could establish an endless loop with `goto`, like this:

```cmd
:SUB_bigRandLooper

set /A lcv=0
:bigRangLooperLoop
set big-rand=!random:~-4!
echo big-rand is !big-rand!
set /A lcv+=1
if !big-rand! gtr 9900 goto :bigRandLooperWrapup
goto :bigRangLooperLoop

:bigRandLooperWrapup
echo biggest-rand is %big-rand%
echo lcv is %lcv%
exit /B
```

I know the `goto` loop is slower than the `for /L` loop, but that is the only way to create a breakable infinite loop.

A faster approach is to nest both loop methods: use `for /L` to iterate a few thousands times and wrap an infinite `goto` loop around.

---

An alternative work-around is to make use of the fact that the `exit` command can break (infinite) `for /L` loops. But since this also exits the `cmd` instance the batch file is running in, the loop needs to be placed into a separate `cmd` instance. Of course the environment is completely separated from the current one. A solution might look like this:

```cmd
:SUB_bigRandLooper
@echo off
rem // Check for argument, interpret it as jump label if given:
if not "%~1"=="" goto %~1

rem /* Establish explicit `cmd` instance for executing the `for /L` loop;
rem    the `for /F` loop implicitly creates the new `cmd` instance for the command
rem    it executes, so we do not have to explicitly call `cmd /C` here; the resulting
rem    values are echoed by the sub-routine and captured here by `for /F`: */
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%I in ('"%~f0" :bigRandLooperLoop') do (
    rem // Assign captured values to environment variables:
    set "big-rand=%%I" & set "lcv=%%J"
)

:bigRandLooperWrapup
echo biggest-rand is %big-rand%
echo lcv is %lcv%
exit /B

:bigRandLooperLoop
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A lcv=0
for /L %%s in (0,0,1) do (
    set big-rand=!random:~-4!
    rem /* Explicitly redirect this output to the console window to prevent it from
    rem    being captured by `for /F` in the main routine too: */
    > con echo big-rand is !big-rand!
    set /A lcv+=1
    if !big-rand! gtr 9900 (
        rem // Output found values in order to be able to capture them by `for /F`:
        echo !big-rand! !lcv!
        rem // Break loop and leave current `cmd` instance:
        exit
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: You can break an infinite `FOR /L` loop with `exit`, but then it should be in a sub process

Comment: @jeb, this breaks any sub-process or sub-script calls, so that is why I kind of ignored that; also fatal errors would break the loop, but the same problems arise...

Comment: @jeb, I added a work-around using a separate `cmd` instance for the `for /L` loop now -- thanks for your input!